# Testing a method that simply calls another method

Tags: apex

I have a Trigger Framework Handler Test Class that extends the TriggerHandler. In the override method, I am only simply calling a method from a different class. How can I do unit test here? Following is the sample code. Thanks.

```
@isTest
public with sharing class MyTriggerHandler_Test extends TriggerHandler {
    @isTest
    public override void afterInsert(){
        MyAnotherClass.methodInMyAnotherClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why will a test class extend TriggerHandler?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why a test class extends TriggerHandler.

You can simply just write a Test Class, and call the handler method from your test class.

For eg:

Lets say you have a trigger handler class as below:

```
public class UserNoticeManagementTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
```

In your test class you can simply do either this:

```
@isTest
private static void testAfterInsert(){
    UserNoticeManagementTriggerHandler.yourmethodname();
}
```

Or just insert data, the trigger handler will run and cover your required lines.

Comment: Right. Thanks. That's all is needed. But what about assert statements? At least one is required, right? as per PMD best practices.

Comment: how will you test abstract class or interface? by extending them in testclass. 

The idea is to test the abstraction and not the actual implementation.

Comment: @STSF If the statement does any DML or return any value, you can assert the return value or the DB value.

Comment: No, this has just one line of code to call another method.